# tokenizing in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to tokenize a string using all non-letter characters as delimiters.

I have a line specifying this:

```
char delimiters[] = "1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+[]\;',./{}|:"<>?"
```

But im pretty sure this is not valid code. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To be pedantic, if you want to check for ALL non-letter characters, you'll need to include tons of octal escapes as well. In practice, these never show up in non-malicious strings though.

Answer (score 2):

Tokenizing a string using the standard library can be done with `strtok`. It has a particular way it expects to be called: on the first call, you pass in your input string and delimiters and `strtok` returns the first token. After that, every time you call `strtok` with `NULL` and the delimiters as parameters you get a subsequent token.

[Consult a reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) for more information. The code example below is based on the one on the linked site.

And as it's been said, you have to escape the `"` and `\` characters by using `\"` and `\\`.

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="This is a sample string: name@example.com";
  const char delimiters[] = "1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+[]\\;',./{}|:\"<>?"
  char * pch;

  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);

  pch = strtok (str, delimiters);
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    // pch now point to a token in your string
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, delimiters);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So someone noted that my delimiters were not enough (because I am trying to filter out only letter characters). Is there a way to incorporate isalpha into this code?

Comment: Unfortunately not. `strtok` is very primitive and only accepts `const char*` as its delimiter argument. You would have to write your own `while` loop and check the input string character by character with `isalpha`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `"` and `\` with a `\`:

```
const char delimiters[] = "1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+[]\\;',./{}|:\"<>?"
```

However, if you really are trying to match "all non-letter characters" (in which case your list of characters is woefully inadequate), you should use a built-in C function such as [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalpha/) instead.

Comment: The `\\` needs to be escaped also.

Comment: so does the \ need a \\ escape too, or is the " the only thing that needs an escape.

Comment: So how would I incorporate as the delimiters?

Comment: The `\ ` needs to be escaped.  The `'` does not. Also, `const char delimiters[]` is optimal. `char delimiters[]` puts the string in writable memory, `char *delimiters` and `const char *delimiters` allocate an extra unnecessary pointer.

Comment: Updated my answer based on Marlon and Zack's input.

Comment: Also, in my experience, the `<ctype.h>` functions are almost never usable, because the character set and encoding of the data stream you're processing doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the global locale of the process.

Comment: Don't drop the `const`, dude.

Comment: Do I need an escape for spaces too?

Comment: No, you don't need to escape spaces.

Comment: So would I just put " " in my delimiters or is it automatically an attribute of strtok?